# Need help understanding the cause of differences in transform-origin and perspective-origin

Tags: html, css, browser

I encountered something at work and I'd like to understand it.

I had copied the *HTML* of a website's header and put it in my own website (I can't provide a link to my site because it's on a private server). I also included all the *CSS* files of the site I was copying. Everything looked identical except for a couple little spots that were taller on my site.

I investigated and found that those spots were every place in which `img` elements were children of `a` elements. I ran *Inspect Element* on both my site and the one I was copying and found out that these `a` and `img` tags had all identical *Rules* and *Computed*, but that that `a`'s were all `3px` taller on my site.

I decided to compare all the *Browser styles*, although I expected nothing would be different, because, of course, I had been comparing in the same browser. Well, it turns out that on my site the `a`'s had different properties for `transform-origin` and `perspective-origin`. I had never even heard of those properties until now, and Firefox did not show them as coming from any *CSS* files.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up very briefly:

***Perspective origin*** is your point in space from which you are looking at the object, whereas ***Transform origin*** is responsible for setting the point over which you are making a rotation or translation with an object. 
You should note that ***perspective*** is responsible for setting the view angle for a given element's children, and thus could explain the slight difference in those properties.